# Include Guards for using a file in multiple places

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

I am probably missing something obvious here but cannot find what.

I have a Utils.h file with a utility function that I want to use in multiple places. I know that the way to avoid redefinition compiler errors is to use include guards.

Here is what I have:

```
//----Utils.h----
#ifndef UH
#define UH
   void UtilFunc() { }
#endif
```

.

```
//----A.h----
class A {
   public:
      A();
      ~A();
};
```

.

```
//----A.cpp----
#include "A.h"
#include "Utils.h"

A::A() {
   UtilFunc();
}

A::~A(){ }
```

.

```
//----main.cpp----
#include "A.h"
#include "Utils.h"

int main() {
   A myA;
   UtilFunc();
   return 0;
}
```

My Visual Studio project has only files A.cpp and main.cpp included and when I try to compile I get:

- Error LNK2005 "void __cdecl UtilFunc(void)" (?UtilFunc@@YAXXZ) already defined in A.obj   HeaderIncludeTest   C:\Users\michalis\source\repos\HeaderIncludeTest\HeaderIncludeTest\main.obj 1
- Error LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  HeaderIncludeTest   C:\Users\michalis\source\repos\HeaderIncludeTest\HeaderIncludeTest\Debug\HeaderIncludeTest.exe  1

Comment: Add header guards for `A.h`

Comment: thanks @cigien but this doesn't resolve it

Comment: Also make `UtilFunc` `inline`.

Comment: I'd also throw it in a namespace.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `inline` solves that without adding any more include guards ! thanks a lot

Comment: You have a redfinition **linker** error and include guards aren't going to help with that.

Comment: @Mikemik Still it's a good idea to have an include guard in every header.

Answer (score 0):

Both `A.cpp` and `main.cpp`  include `Utils.h`, therefore they both have a definition of `UtilFunc`, because you *defined* `UtilFunc` in `Utils.h`. It is a violation of [one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) to have mutiple definitions of a non-inline function in one program. The linker detects it and complains about it.

You should either make `UtilFunc` inline, or put its definition in a separate compilation unit, `Utils.cpp` for example.

```
// Utils.h
#ifndef UH
#define UH
   void UtilFunc();
#endif
```

```
// Utils.cpp
void UtilFunc() {}
```